# Can't decrypt file, which was encrypted on server side with OpenSSL AES 256 CBC

Tags: ios, encryption, openssl, aes

I'm trying to solve this problem for a long time, but still can't get the result. I use [this openssl library](https://github.com/st3fan/ios-openssl) for iOS with [this example code](https://rstforums.com/forum/64053-aes-encryption-decryption-demo-program-using-openssl-evp-apis.rst). If i encrypt data using this code, i also can decrypt this one. but if i encrypt data using Terminal and openssl command, encrypted file can't be decrypted with this code.. Is there some differences or some things, that don't let me finish decryption with success.. I'll be so glad to any advice or suggestion..
Thanks.

UPD:
command, which i used:
openssl aes-256-cbc -in test.pdf -out test.bin -kfile key -S salt_in_hex

Comment: Please post OpenSSL command used?

Comment: openssl aes-256-cbc -in test.pdf -out test.bin -kfile key -S salt_in_hex

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you are missing is that in the code example they are using a key and iv derivation function: `EVP_BytesToKey, not a raw key, google it. Also you are missing the iv which is essentially required for CBC mode.

Best not to use OpenSSL in iOS. Appel does not supply it because version updates are many times not backward compatible breaking older code. Best to use the CommonCrypto function supplied with iOS.

If you are interested in using security in a produce plan on several hundred hours learning about it. The encryption  part is the simple part. If you are just playing with this to learn, consider some books like *Applied Cryptography* by Bruce Schneier and the *Handbook of Applied Cryptography* available free online. Even these badly scratch the surface of proper application of cryptography.

Comment: Thanks for answer. Best not to use OpenSSL in iOS? But what are the alternatives? I want to use not only iOS, i mean i need, for example, to encrypt something on server(not in iOS) side and than to decrypt this in iOS and Android. I'm not sure, that CommonCrypto will help me.